# mongoDB Compass distinct query renders no results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I've been trying to write a distinct query against my mongoDB collection housed in Atlas.

I wanted to get a list of all the distinct values captured within the "Section" attribute under its "MetaData" parent attribute. According to the mongoDB [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/command/distinct/?_ga=2.106346112.2012923831.1653606745-1044793339.1626627747) the syntax to get an array of distinct values is the following syntax:

```
{ distinct: "<collection>", key: "<field>" }
```

My sample collection called "simple" holds the following documents

```
[{
  "_id": "527c61082241f813c09c722c",
  "MetaData": {
    "Type": "BlogPost",
    "Author": "author1",
    "Section": "section1"
  },
  "Title": "title 1",
  "Description": "..."
},
{
  "_id": "527c61082241f813c09c7050",
  "MetaData": {
    "Type": "BlogPost",
    "Author": "author1",
    "Section": "section1"
  },
  "Title": "title 2",
  "Description": "..."
},
{
  "_id": "527c61082241f813c09c7042",
  "MetaData": {
    "Type": "BlogPost",
    "Author": "author1",
    "Section": "section2"
  },
  "Title": "title 3",
  "Description": "..."
  }
]
```

yet when I execute the following filter query in Compass or Atlas's - no results are returned ???

```
 {distinct: 'simple',key: 'MetaData.Section'}
```

I was expecting an array holding "section1" and "section2"

**Can someone tell what I'm doing incorrectly please**
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use aggregation framework for compass to get distinct values

```
{
   $group:{
     "_id": null,
     "sections": { $addToSet: "$MetaData.Section"}
   }
}
```